# RestrictionsFactoryUtil.in() works with MySQL, fails with MS SQL Server. Need viable workaround

Tags: java, sql-server, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I'm having trouble making an API call: 
    `RestrictionsFactoryUtil.in("columnName", ListofIDs);`

The function `com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.RestrictionsFactoryUtil.in()` works properly when my app passes a list of *more than* 2100 records using `MySQL`, but the same method with `MS SQL Server DB` generates the following exception (based on [Max Capacity Specs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15))

> *The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a
>   maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend
>   the request.*

Online forums suggest using Table value parameter at DB level, but, unfortunately that would entail a major change to my application.

I want to avoid DB level changes and stored procedures. My app has a substantial dependency on [LIFERAY Dynamic Query utility](https://proliferay.com/liferay-dynamic-query-api/). I really hoping to avoid workarounds that require dropping that dependency.

Comment: This *might* not be a great question for StackOverflow, because it's less about coding specifics and more about servers and infrastructure. You may be more successful getting help if you post this question to another StackExchange network site, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: Also check out StackExchange [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com)